# Numpy random.choice probablities don't sum up to 1

Tags: python, numpy, random, pytorch

I wanna randomly select sample points based on the probability distribution specified by `prob` for a given row. However, I get the error in `np.random.choice` that the probabilities don't add up to 1. This is very weird because I first normalize using the L1-norm along the rows and then I define a uniform distribution if the values are smaller than the threshold 1e-6.

```
import numpy as np
import torch.nn.functional as F

prob = F.normalize(outputs, p=1, dim=1).clone().data.cpu().numpy() # outputs is a torch.Tensor of shape (14, 6890)
all_zero = np.where(prob.max(1) < 1e-6)[0] # find indices of rows where all values are smaller
prob[all_zero] = np.full(prob.shape[1], 1 / prob.shape[1]) # fill those rows uniformly
# ... somewhere later inside a method
for j in range(14):
    sample = np.random.choice(6890, 4, replace=False, p=prob[j])
```

Do you understand, why that is?

Comment: After the line `prob[all_zero] = ...`, add `print(prob.sum(axis=1))`.  What is the output?

Comment: It's 0.15683803.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As error suggests `prob[j]` doesn't sum to `1`.

Your epsilon `1e-6` is way too big to be considered insignificant, there is no need for this operation at all. If you insist, you have to redistribute zero-ed out values across what's left to 1 (and it seems you did just that actually).

All in all you didn't normalize the array to 1:

```
prob /= prob.sum(axis=1) # make it prob dist
```

BTW. Broadcasting will extend your single number to the whole row, no need for `np.full`:

```
prob[all_zero] = 1 / prob.shape[1]
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm gonna try this. I'm doing this because at some point, the outputs from the neural network I'm training become zero. Hence to catch the error, I insert the all_zero approach.

Comment: `prob[all_zero] = np.full(all_zero, (1 - np.sum(prob)) / len(all_zero))` doesn't really make sense, the first entry to `np.full` is the shape of the array to be filled. Also, `np.sum(prob)` is larger than 1 (obviously after normalizing all rows).

Comment: Yeah, my bad, misread it, don't know why I assumed your rows sum up to one, fixed my answer hopefully. You were just missing the step to make it probability distribution.